# exclude file in window dialog OSX

Tags: java, macos, file, select, processing

I try to exclude type file from window dialog. 
[image: what i need in my window]

```
void setup() {
  selectFolder("Select a folder to process:", "folderSelected");
}

void folderSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or the user hit cancel.");
  } else {
    println("User selected " + selection.getAbsolutePath());
    printArray(getFolderContent(selection));
  }
}

import java.io.FilenameFilter;
static final String[] exts = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".tiff", ".tif"};

static final FilenameFilter pictsFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
  boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = exts.length; i-- != 0;) {
        if (name.endsWith(exts[i]))  {
            return true;
        }
      }
    return false;
  }
};

static final File[] getFolderContent(File dir) {
  return dir.listFiles(pictsFilter);
}
```

I don't want use `JChooser` because it's very uggly and old `UI`. I try with `FileDialog` because the window using to display files have a OSX design correspondance. But I don't find anycode to set the possibility to exclude type file when the window is open. The only thing I find it's exclude the file after have select folder by using this code below ; but I don't find this solution very nice !
My purpose is can see directly in the window if the file is authorized or not.

Comment: [`FileDialog#setFilenameFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#setFilenameFilter(java.io.FilenameFilter))? If you want anything else then you'll probably need to look towards and JNI/JNA based solution

Comment: That's can be used easily with Processing for a junior programmer ?

Answer (score 1):

To use a file name filter you will need to create it and set it on your file dialog.

```
final String[] exts = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".tiff", ".tif"};
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(frame, "select file", FileDialog.LOAD);
dialog.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i <  exts.length; i++) {
            if (name.endsWith(exts[i]))  {
                return true;
            }
          }
        return false;
    }}
);
```

Note that according to the javadoc:

> Filename filters do not function in Sun's referenceimplementation for Microsoft Windows.

Comment: You're a magician, I think it's a same problem like the multi selection... the order of my methods. thx a lot for this simple and magic solution.